# RStatistics: Setting date as variable in MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, r, rmysql

Connecting to a database via RMySQL I wrote some R-scripts - to make them easier: Is it possible to set the date in MySQL Query as a variable?

e.g.

```
x<-"2012-12-01"

rs <- dbGetQuery(db,"**** where date between 'x' and '2012-12-31'")
```

Is there any possibility or is everything in "" just MySQL stuff?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `paste` to dynamically write your query:

```
x<-'2012-12-01'
query <-  paste("**** where date between '",x,"' and '2012-12-31'",sep='')
```

This will creates a query like:

```
"**** where date between '2012-12-01' and '2012-12-31'"
```

Then

```
 rs <- dbGetQuery(db,query)
```